# insert an object for all my objects in a model django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to add a new object from a model to all my model's objects

Example:
I have a model Train which has many trains in it.
Now I have another Model Car which has 6 cars.

I want all my trains in the Train model to have the 6 cars in it.

In fact, If I would like to add, by using the admin interface, a new car (car 7), I would like all my trains to have it without having to select all the trains.
Also, if I want to add a new train, I should have the 6 cars in it directly without having to go in the model Car and add the new train.

I have declared my models as the following:

```
class Train(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Car(models.Model):
    train = models.ManyToManyField(Train)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I can't make this work, please help me....

EDIT: picture of the actual result in admin interface:
[image: add a car]

Comment: I think your Models is correct according to your requirement.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your fast answer. no, actually I have to select all the trains in my Model Car from the admin page. If I add a new train, it doesnt have the cars in it. I edited the post so you can see what I am getting.

Comment: Can you little but explain like is this you want all trains are in all cars and all cars in all trains. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: No, I want each train in Train to have all the cars in Car model, so if I add a new train it will have all the car in it directly. All the trains have the same cars.

Comment: If it can help you understand, we are making trains. It's a chain production. All the trains are same and so they have the same components. But if we receive a new order, and we have to make more trains, I would like to have just to add a new train from the admin page and all the components of the train should be added to this new train. If you see what I mean

Comment: So don't make any relationship, as far as my knowledge goes because. It is not solving any purpose. If you need it at time of showing you can fetch all cars for every train

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212040/discussion-between-dhruv-agarwal-and-roman-baron).

Comment: sure. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider my idea to add additional query to fetch all the cars at time of Views.

Models should look like

```
class Car(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
return self.name


class Train(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
return self.name
```